# non-zero float is generated as \0 in sprintf

Tags: c, linker, printf, newlib, psoc

I'm working with PSoC Creator, and I'm trying to print a float between -1 and 1 to an I2C OLED.
To get this working I'm using the function `sprintf`. I added the following flag to my linker `-u _printf_float` because I'm using newlib-nano and it omits float handling code if not requested.  (my problem might have to do something with this... maybe?)

For testing purposes I wrote the lines:

```c
char stringbuffer[20];
sprintf(stringbuffer, "(%1.1f, %1.1f)", 1.1, 1.1);
```

While debugging I noticed that every non-zero float I try to print is printed as garbage, with a null character up front. Actually every non-zero float is replaced by the following 3 bytes. If I replace all the values with `0.0` then it is printed perfectly fine.

```
0x00 '\000'
0x2E '.'
0x80 '\200'
```

The integers that I'm trying to print in the following line are behaving as expected.

Anyone that ran into a similar problem?

Comment: Not sure it's the cause of the problem, but the `%1.1f` format looks a bit weird. This is asking for a (total) width of `1` character and `1` digit after the decimal. Try `%3.1f`?

Comment: @AdrianMole The first  `1` is the _minimum_ width, not total width. Still a tad weird.   I doubt it is part of the problem.

Comment: Does code use a proper prototype for `sprintf()`?,  Proper linking?

Comment: cannot reproduce https://godbolt.org/z/346q37 voting to close

Comment: @AdrianMole you're right, shouldn't have added the 1 in front of the period. But that is not the problem.

Comment: I found in this post: https://www.cypress.com/comment/305501 that adjusting the heap size might help. In this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746062/snprintf-prints-garbage-floats-with-newlib-nano it is mentioned that it might be a problem with the linker (which goes way above my skill-level) Testing it tomorrow, and will report back if it's fixed.

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland That is because you're working with a different toolchain. I will be reporting back for future reference if I find a working solution. I found two possibilities already, see my other comments.

Comment: @Typhaon you should mention uCs. By default most implementations do not print floats. You need to: -u_printf_float

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland I already stated that I did that in my original post

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Can you elaborate? what do you mean with proper prototype? sprintf works perfectly with integers, and floats equal to 0.

Comment: @Typhaon it does not matter hewre

Comment: @Typhaon Without a function prototype for `sprintf()`, 1) the compiler may not compiler code (which it apparently did for you), 2) make assumptions about types (which would be a problem with `char */int` incompatibility or 3)  perhaps work OK.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with sprintf(), using newlib-nano with floating-point support enabled.

The issue is caused by insufficient heap space.
In PSoC Creator, in the Workspace Explorer pane, navigate to System.
Expand "Configuration", then change Heap Size (bytes) from the default 0x80 to 0x200. Rebuild, and run.